# how to increase performance for reading and writing large text file?

Tags: c#, performance, io

i have written a program to clean some financial data i have collected over the months. it's about 100GB in total and growing everyday, and each file is about 1-2GB each. it is currently stored in a text file format.

the code below is use to clean the data:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        string inputString;
        string outputString;

             // others variable omitted

        string[] lineSplit;

        foreach (string fullPath in Directory.GetFiles(inputDirectory))
        {

            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fullPath))        //read from input file
            {
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                          //logic to clean data

                                ...

                         ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

                    using (StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText(outputFile))
                    {
                        writer.WriteLine(outputString);
                    }
                }
            }
        }       
    }
```

it is very slow, i estimate for 100GB of data it will take me about 3-4 days to finish it. i know it is about my IO operation, as i have no buffer etc to do it. i am still relatively new to C# and i couldn't find any relevant example to build a proper buffer for IO. most example i find are for downloading and not applicable to reading text files. And i cant load the whole file into memory to process it as it is too big. how can i do it? can anyone give me some snippet of code i can use? thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're reopening the output file on *every single line*. Move the loop to *inside* the block which starts by calling `File.AppendText`:

```
using (TextReader reader = File.OpenText(fullPath))
{
    using (TextWriter writer = File.AppendText(outputFile))
    {
         while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
         {
             // Logic to clean data
            writer.WriteLine(outputString);
         }
    }
}
```

Of course this assumes you've got one output file per input file. If that's not the case - if each line can go to a different file within a small collection - you may want to keep all the output files open, and just keep a dictionary (or something similar) so you can quickly write to whichever you want.

Comment: random aside - Jon - did we (SE) break your tracker? Are you out of quota?

Comment: @MarcGravell: Yup. Bizarrely enough it *does* show 10 points for me on Meta yesterday, but SO is a blank. I was going to try to look into it tomorrow.

Comment: if nothing is obviously wrong at your end, do let us know which methods you're calling - I'm sure we can convince Monty to look at it ;p

Comment: in particular, it *is* coming back with data: https://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/users/22656/reputation?fromdate=1344816000&site=stackoverflow

Comment: @MarcGravell: Righto. I'll look tonight.

Comment: @ClaytonLeung: I wouldn't bother adding buffering unless you find there's a need to. Try that change first.

Comment: @jon skeet, if i have like 20 output files? do i need to nest the using outputfile statement 20 times?, that would makes my code very messy to read?

Comment: @ClaytonLeung: As I said in my answer, you'd probably want to have something like a dictionary of open files. You'd need to add a try/finally block so that you'd close them all at the end though.